# Using Open Graph to see what comments are being made

Tags: api, programming

I know that I can get the number of links shared from Facebook's Open Graph with something like this:

```
 http://graph.facebook.com?id=http://thanetstar.com/article/what-s-great-about-thanet-2
```

And I get back the URL and the share count. However I would like to see the comments on these shares as I would if I was clicking to see who had shared them.

Does anyone know if Facebook's Open Graph API support this or if the data can be accessed with sufficient know-how and a bit of good old fashioned hard work (for my server anyway)?

Comment: Maybe this question fits better in stackoverflow?

Comment: I would have thought so but the mods there seem to have a thing for telling me I should have put the question somewhere else. As this was about data access I hoped this was the best place. I hope I've not upset anyone by appearing to be a bit of a noobie about this.

Comment: It's not the case of upset someone, but to find someone to help you. Probably you will find one here as well. I will try to find a solution too.

Answer (score 3):

As I said before, I made a small research about your question. Here is what I've found.

Your url give me this response:

URL: http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://thanetstar.com/article/what-s-great-about-thanet-2

```
Response: {
   "id": "http://thanetstar.com/article/what-s-great-about-thanet-2",
   "shares": 19
}
```

But if I use the same call for another website, I get this response

URL: [LINK](https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/scandal-shonda-rhimes-kerry-washington-olivia-pope-308845)

```
{
   "http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/scandal-shonda-rhimes-kerry-washington-olivia-pope-308845": {
      "id": "http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/scandal-shonda-rhimes-kerry-washington-olivia-pope-308845",
      "shares": 67,
      "comments": 2
   }
}
```

You can see that in your link, even if you have comments in the site, response doesn't include them. I don't know why. Maybe you haven't used the OG meta tags with the right way.

**Also, I found that this link will return the comments from a OG object:**

URL: https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://thanetstar.com/article/what-s-great-about-thanet-2

My source: [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Open-Graph/How-do-you-post-comments-to-a-URL-or-article-object-on-the-Facebook-Open-Graph)

Comment: That's my findings too. However the comments data appears to be empty... I guess I need a public share with a comment on it? I'm not sure.